# Eclipse neon installer hangs

Tags: eclipse, installation, offline, eclipse-neon

Eclipse Neon installation is different from earlier eclipse versions when you could download everything at once. Now Eclipse installer is a program that starts to download. Every time I tried to install from different computer from different places, the install process hangs.

Any solution, suggestion or workaround will be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: If someone votes down, give a reason. If not you are spreading ignorance, making a possible solution unreachable :)

Comment: You can still download a package. Look for the link under the button that downloads the installer.

Comment: You are correct

Answer (score 1):

The online installer is present as the main option
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

but there is a small greyed link called "Download Packages"
which allow us to download eclipse the usual way taking us to
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/